# Permutations of sets within larger sets

Tags: permutations

I am trying to find a formula to give me the number of permutations of 3 numbers across multiple sets of numbers. For example I have 5 different sets call them a,b,c,d,e with numbers 1-10 and I want to know if we use one number from each how many permutations of just 3 there are across these sets ie  a1, d3, e2.

There can only be one number per letter - no combinations of say a1,a2,b3.

The letters must follow in order ie c cannot come before b.

I am interested to see the formula itself so that the number of sets can be increased as necessary but I am only interested in permutations of 3.

Many thanks,

Gordon

Comment: Are the subsets $a_1,d_3,e_2$ and $b_1,d_3,e_2$ identical as far as you're concerned? If not (i.e., they are considered different), then simply choose $3$ out of $5$ sets, and then choose $1$ out of $10$ numbers from each set. So the number of combinations is $\binom53\cdot10^3$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Barak, I would consider them to be different. I am not that clued up on entering formulas so how would yours be entered on a calculator and what result would it give ?

Comment: $\binom53\cdot10^3=\frac{5!}{3!\cdot2!}\cdot1000=10000$.

Comment: So if I follow correctly that would make 120,000 combinations if we looked for the same size of subsets 3 from 10 sets ?

Comment: Looks like it...

Comment: You're a gentleman - thank you very much